# Pythonic method of increasing two counters depending on boolean check

Tags: python

I am attempting to get a ratio of good spellings / bad spellings in a text compared to the overall text. I have a method that counts the number of misspellings, but it seems to be somewhat bloated. Is there a more pythonic way of increasing my `good` / `bad` counters in my for loop?

```
import enchant
from enchant.tokenize import get_tokenizer, HTMLChunker, EmailFilter, URLFilter

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
good = 0
bad = 0
text = "this is <span class='stupid'>not important</span>. Email you@example.com from http://www.google.com. htis si a msispelling"
tokenizer = get_tokenizer("en_US", (HTMLChunker,),(URLFilter,EmailFilter))

# This loop here: Can I make this more efficient?
for (word,pos) in tokenizer(text):
    if d.check(word):
        good += 1
    else:
        bad += 1

print good   # Prints 7
print bad    # Prints 3
```

Comment: Comparing to the answers below I think your code is still the best when it comes to speed and memory efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Pythonic" generally means most straight-forward or easiest to read, so I won't claim that. But this takes advantage of some tricks that might be faster.

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(d.check(word) for (word,pos) in tokenizer(text))
good, bad = counts[True], counts[False]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following

```
tokens = list(tokenizer(text))
good = sum(d.check(word) for word, _ in tokens)
bad = len(tokens) - good
```

This is taking advantage of the fact that Python will interpret `False` as `0` and `True` as `1`, for example

```
>>> sum([True, True, True])
3
```

So in the above code, summing the result of the list comprehension will be summing a list of `True` and `False` values, which is effectively the same as summing only the `True` values.

Then the `bad` number is the total number minus the `good`.

Comment: Note that the object returned by `tokenizer(text)` is an iterator, so this is not going to work.

Comment: In Python 2, you can take advantage of the comprehension scoping rules and use `[d.check(word) for total, (word, pos) in enumerate(tokens)]` instead. After the call to `sum`, `total` will still hold the number of items returned by the iterator. In Python 3, `total` would be local to the comprehension and not available to compute the value of `bad`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I didn't realize this. I added a list comp to address that.

Comment: Few more things: Replace the first LC with `list()` call(manual iteration to materialize an iterator is slow) and drop the `[]` from `sum()` call. Lastly I've found that something like `sum(1 for x in foo if some_condition)` always outperforms the version that relies on `True==1` and `False==0` equality, I don't know why exactly but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Since `good` and `bad` are somewhat related, use a dictionary instead.

```
counts = { 'good': 0, 'bad': 0 }

counts[ 'good' if d.check(word) else 'bad' ] += 1
```

This probably isn't significantly more efficient in terms of execution time.

Comment: Or `counts = [0, 0];counts[d.check(word)] += 1;...;bad, good = counts`

Comment: I like to be overly explicit :)  I considered something in between, `counts = { True: 0, False: 0}`.